# Login issue in aix server

Tags: aix

while login as root in an aix server, i am changing the password of a user. However, when trying to login to the server from that user id, it shows password expired and You must change your password now and login again!

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **ADMCHG** flag of password for an user directs the system to ask for password change on login. You can find this flag for an user's password in the file `/etc/security/passwd` or with `pwdadm` command.

**Eg.**

```
# grep -p "username:" /etc/security/passwd
username:
        password = EvqNjMMwJzXnc
        lastupdate = 1274003127
        flags =       ADMCHG

# pwdadm -q username
username:
        lastupdate = 1274003127
        flags = ADMCHG
```

Clear all the flags:

```
# pwdadm -c username
```

See also: [Password expiry](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-password_expiry/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much.... after acting the above mentioned changes in the server as root.... now i am able to enter to it from the user id......

Comment: @Biswajit You're welcome. if you think the answer was helpful don't forget to accept it.

Comment: hw do i accept the same...???

Comment: take a look in this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.